# Is this non-locked TryGetValue() dictionary access thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dictionary, thread-safety

```
private object lockObj = new object();

private Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

public string GetOrAddFromDict(int key)
{
    string value;

    // non-locked access:
    if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        return value;

    lock (this.lockObj)
    {
        if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            return value;

        string newValue = "value of " + key; // place long operation here
        dict.Add(key, newValue);

        return newValue;
    }
}
```

**Question a:** Is it thread-safe? If yes, why?

**Question b:** How is this double-TryGetValue() pattern called?

Comment: Side note; that pattern of double-checked locking *is* explicitly safe for `Hashtable`. It is less clear whether that is safe for dictionary.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

a) This is not thread-safe, as the underlying `Dictionary` itself is not thread safe.  If another thread is calling Add at the same time, undefined behavior can occur.

b) This is effectively an attempt at [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

I would recommend using the [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) class instead, as it's designed for this scenario.  Another option would be to use a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) (or [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx)), if you're not targetting .NET 4.0.

Comment: -1 ReaderWriterLockSlim and ReaderWriterLock are far more expensive than 'lock', especially on write.  The only reason to use these is when your doing something like 100 or 1000 reads for every write AND the duration of read lock is significant enough to cause substantial delays on the other threads.  With code this trivial (a single TryGetValue) the 'lock' statement is the correct synchronization.

Comment: @csharptest.net that's harsh; his recommendation was `ConcurrentDictionary`, which would be fine - and since Reed isn't the OP, **we don't know** the reader/writer rate. `ReaderWriterLockSlim` might actually be fine, for all we know.

Comment: @csharptest The following blog entry claims the performance overhead of `ReaderWriterLockSlim` over `Monitor` is about a factor 2. From your comment I expected a factor beyond 10. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/10/07/a-performance-comparison-of-readerwriterlockslim-with-readerwriterlock.aspx

Comment: @Marc Gravell, Fair enough I am being a little harsh, but to get a -1 on a +5 answer isn't going to hurt Reed's rep any ;) ConcurrentDictionary was suggested; however, this class is 4.0 only and we don't know what version the OP is using.  Thus his recommendation of the other locks can cause serious performance issues.  As noted using these Reader/Writer locks requires not only a threshold of read:write ratio, but also requires a complex (or time consuming) read/write process to be benefitial.  I was only trying to ensure that the OP did not stray down a very painful road.

Comment: @Reed Copsey, Sorry for the -1 on an otherwise very good answer.  I hope that my comment above explains my reasoning.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I read the same blog when I wrote this comparison: http://csharptest.net/?p=485  I think his tests were flawed and did not produce a real-world sampling.  You might expect 2n performance if you only use the Write method; but then what would be the point of that?  In the end I gave up on both ReaderWriterLockSlim and ReaderWriterLock as they both suck under different circumstances.  I wound up building one from a Monitor http://csharptest.net/browse/src/Library/Synchronization/SimpleReadWriteLocking.cs which has it's own issues but performs well under all cases I tested.

Comment: @csharptest.net: I mentioned using ReaderWriterLockSlim here because the OP's intent was obviously to NOT take a lock on read, so I'm assuming (which may be false) that access is heavily balanced towards reading - otherwise, this would be an unnecessary optimization.  Granted, the OP may be trying to do pre-mature optimization here (highly possible), but I'm giving them the benefit of the doubt.  If, and only if, there are many reads per write, I'd strongly stand by using RWLS over lock in .NET 3.5...

Comment: @Reed Copsey, you wrote "... If, and only if, there are many reads per write, ..." I guess this is sticky point, workload matters.  In my testing RWLock or RWLockSlim will both be twice as slow as Monitor when your not doing any significant work inside the lock.  In this example, if !TryGetValue() then Add(), is operationally too fast to justify the reader/writer locking overhead.  Mostly this is a nit-picky micro optimization that in the grand scheme of things is meaningless, except that using the reader/writer locks add a lot of unnecessary complexity by the introduction of try/catch logic.

Comment: havent tested but we can wrap in a try catch block and fall back to locking.

Comment: It would be an option to try to access the dictionary with `while(!dict.TryGetValue(key, out value);`? I found that this snipped is twice faster than using the lock(obj), but I'm not sure it will always work. In my method, the dictionary is accessed by all the threads, which are removing and adding keys, but I can guarantee that only a single thread access a given key. This would be sufficient?

Answer (score 14):

> Question a: Is it thread-safe? If yes, why?

Not only is it not thread safe; it will also throw with NullReferenceException if accessed while another thread is reorganizing the hash buckets.  The lock statement is wicked fast, don't avoid it.

> Question b: How is this double-TryGetValue() pattern called?

It's called a 'bug' by most people ;)

Comment: *It's called a 'bug' by most people* made me LOL ;) +1

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, no.

I carry around a custom HashMap that has this property.

The defect is in the rehash() function.